# List of events supported by Web Based Outlook Add ins

Tags: office-js, office-addins

VSTO based outlook Add-in provides many events like AppointmentItem.Open, .Close, .AttachmentAdd, .AttachmentRemove, .Write, .AfterWrite, .Send, .AutoSave etc.
I want to know all the list of events supported by WebBased Outlook Add-ins.

As per my understanding same outlook add in would work for outlook client as well as on OWA. 
I am really not sure whether this kind of events OWA can support however, would like to know anything can be done to support these events for Outlook client.

I am referring below microsoft link for outlook add-ins but don't find all the details there. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/

Appreciate if you can point me some documentation around event.s

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: Supported events are listed in [`Office.EventType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.eventtype?view=office-js) enum.

Comment: Thanks @SlavaIvanov.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very, very few events exposed by web add-ins:

- AppointmentTimeChanged
- ItemChanged
- RecipientsChanged
- RecurrenceChanged

The documentation explains these events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office#eventtype-string. You can create hooks into these events via [Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox.item#addhandlerasynceventtype-handler-options-callback).